# How to refine the pattern and remove the brackets in output?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that prints a diagonal pattern. The arguments to this are:

1. The number of columns (stars) in each line
2. The number of lines
3. The length of the gap between two consecutive stars on each line.

This is what I have tried:

```
def pattern(s, r, g):
    for i in range(r):
        print(" " * g, ("*", " " * g) * s, end="\n")
```

But the output looks like this: for pattern(2,3,4) where 2 is the number of stars in each row, 3 is the number of rows and 4 is the number of gaps between the stars

```
('*', '    ', '*', '    ')
('*', '    ', '*', '    ')
('*', '    ', '*', '    ')
```

How can I execute this without the brackets?

Comment: but in that case i only get one star without the stars repeating for the number specified in the arguments.

Comment: Do you want commas and quotes in output?

Comment: no i do not! i only need the stars

Comment: i'm using python 3

Comment: I don't see any diagonal pattern. Is it a work in progress? How should it look like at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out tuples. You need to unpack tuple using `*` operator:

```
def pattern(s, r, g):
    for i in range (r):
        print(' ' * g, *('*', ' ' * g) * s, end='\n')

pattern(2, 3, 4)
```

**Output**:

```
     *      *
     *      *                                                    
     *      *
```

Comment: Ah i see! Thanks so much! It works perfectly well now! I was not aware of unpacking the tuple using the asterisk!

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more loop

```
    for i in range (r):
        for j in range(s):
            print('*', ' '*g, end='')
        print('\n')

pattern(3,5,8)
```

Output :

```
*         *         *         

*         *         *         

*         *         *         

*         *         *         

*         *         *
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to printing out tuples / expanding the tuples, you could simply print a string built by concatenating the different string parts using `+`, e.g.

```
def pattern(s, r, g):
    for i in range(r):
        print(" " * g + ("*" + " " * g) * s, end="\n")


pattern(2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
     *      *
     *      *                                                    
     *      *
```

Note that `end="\n"` is superfluous here, and there seems to be no diagonal pattern.